# what does the command " tar cvf - . " do ?

Tags: unix, tar

What does the command"tar cvf - . "do ?

Complete command is something like below.

Command : tar cvf - . | ( ssh pppdc9prd7s0 "cd/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/db ; tar xvf -" )

Comment: try running: `man tar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates(`c`) new archive from current directory(`.`) and writes it to the standard output (`f -`).

Answer (score 0):

If you run the command in terminal `man tar` it will bring up a manual which describes what each does.

The following are what each command does:

-c, --create
           create a new archive

-v, --verbose
           verbosely list files processed

-f, --file ARCHIVE
           use archive file or device ARCHIVE

Comment: i was interested in knowing (f-) part. Thanks for enlightening me on "man" :D

Comment: That's alright, don't forget to accept it as an answer if you think it's correct :)